# How to create type for interface in gRPC Protobuf?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

We have common Auth service for all microservices.
When we validate request in response, we send JSON that look like this.

```
{
    Auth: bool,
    Body: interface{}
}
```

While writing proto3 syntax, how can we write something like an interface type?

I have tried using Any type, but I am not able to use it as we need to pass message type in type url which I am not able to generate.

Proto message for response

```
message AuthResponse {
    bool Auth = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any Body = 2;
}
```

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `body` type to `bytes`.

If you have a pre-defined set of types that your body could be, then I suggest you change your `Auth` struct to something like this:

```
type AuthResponse struct {
    Auth bool
    Body Encodable
}

// Encodable defines types that can be encoded into a byte slice.
type Encodable interface {
    Encode() []byte
}
```

Then, implement `Encode() []byte` on each of your types.

Alternatively, if your `Body` field can be *anything*, then perhaps a similar solution, except your `Encode` function would look like this:

`func Encode(interface{}) []byte`

In this scenario, though, you may have to use some reflection magic in order to encode it to some byte slice. You could even use `JSON`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How can I decode it back to `interface{}` type in the other end without knowing the type (as it can be anything)? i.e I got message.Body as []byte, now I want to use it as an interface (not knowing the type so I can't use something like `json.Unmarshal()`)